# How to convert date and time format to timestamp in React Native using moment?

Tags: react-native, momentjs

I need to convert date and time in format like: `moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss")` to timestamp ? How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let date = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month - 1, day, hour, minute, second));
let timeStamp =  date.getTime() / 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is possible with both `Date` and `Moment`, try this

```
const moment = require('moment')

const time = moment() // moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss")

const timestamp = {
    unix: time.unix(),
    utc: time.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
}
```

output `{ unix: 1605126864, utc: '2020-11-11 17:34:24' }`

if you want to work with [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone')

const time = moment().tz('America/Sao_Paulo')
```